# Transparent UINavigationBar, but with blur

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uitabbar

By default, the `UINavigationBar` (and this appears to be valid to `UITabBar` as well) has a blur effect and is tinted white (with some translucency).

What I would like to have is a fully transparent (not translucent!) bar, and keep the blurriness of what's behind it. Here's a mockup:
[image]

If I try to set a custom bar tint color like this:
`[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBarTintColor:someColorWithAlphaLessThanOne];`
The bar will, however, be tinted with a color exactly the same RGB values, but alpha forced to 1. In other words, the bar will be opaque.

If I set the navigation bar's background image to a new `UIImage`, then it will be fully transparent, but will not have the blur effect.

How can I remove the white tint and keep the blur?

Comment: Let's say it is _not_ a navigation bar. Do you know how to make a blur like the one you want?

Comment: On iOS 8, yes, I do. Using `UIVisualEffect`. On iOS 7 I'd probably need some thing like FXBlurView, but I am not sure I can achieve the full transparency effect with either of them

Comment: Okay, so the UIVisualEffect blur is acceptable. That's what I wanted to know. So why not use a fully transparent UINavigation bar, with a UIVisualEffect blur view behind it?

Comment: Not quite what I expected: http://cl.ly/image/0Z2l340C2k1e/Image%202015-05-02%20at%205.24.31%20PM.png

Comment: Well, that is why I asked you if the UIVisualEffect blur was acceptable. You see, I do not know how you expect to obtain the very gentle blur you have drawn. You need to start by saying how to obtain it - in general, completely outside of the UINavigationBar world.

Comment: That's why I said "not sure I can achieve the full transparency effect". Anyway, I think this is good start. I noticed that if I remove the first subview of the navigation bar the result is better than that image, so maybe I'm gonna start working on top of that.

Comment: Guilherme, have you gotten anywhere on this question?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to use a custom `UIView` for the navigation bar, and hide the actual navigation bar. You can then blur either by screenshotting, or using `UIVisualEffect`, or [`LFGlassView`](https://github.com/radi/LiveFrost) (if you want to support iOS 7 as well)